# Legendre's Equation, sturm liouville - eigenvalues/eigenfunction

Tags: eigenfunctions, legendre-polynomials, sturm-liouville

[Linear Differential Equation,Legendre's Equation, sturm liouville - eigenvalues/eigenfunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJNXf.png)

> Consider the linear differential operator:
>   $$ L = \frac{1}{4}(1+x^2)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}x(1+x^2)\frac{d}{dx}+a $$
>   acting on functions defined in $-1 \le x \le 1$ and vanishing at the endpoints of the interval.
>   (a) Is $L$ Hermitian? 
>   (b) Determine the weight function necessary to make $L$ Hermitian. 
>   (c) Show explicitly that
>   $$
>    \int_{-1}^{1}V^*(x)W(x)Lu(x)dx = \int_{-1}^{1}(LV)^*W(x)u(x)dx
> $$
>   and thereby determine the condition on 'a'.
>   (d) Change variables to
>   $$ x= \tan\left(\frac{\Theta}{2}\right) $$
>   Find $2$ even eigenfunctions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ of the diferential equation
>   $$ Lu=\lambda u. $$

It's my first time posting question, so wasn't sure how to type the differential equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I know, I am new to this and still practicing. The equations weren't coming the way I wanted them to.

Comment: You can take a look at how I edited your question. That will help you learn MathJax for the next time.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not Legendre's equation; Legendre's equation is singular at $x=\pm 1$ because it has $1-x^2$ instead of $1+x^2$. Your operator may be written in selfadjoint form as
$$
        Lf = \frac{1}{4}((1+x^2)f')'+af
$$

This operator is symmetric on $[-1,1]$ with respect to weight function $1$, assuming you impose the stated conditions $f(-1)=f(1)=0$. That is, if $f,g$ vanish at the endpoints, then
$$
   \int_{-1}^{1}\{(Lf)g-fLg\}dx =0.
$$
This follows from the fact that $f,g$ vanish at $\pm 1$, and from the Lagrange identity:
$$
    (Lf)g-f(Lg) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{4}(1+x^2)(f'g-fg')\right)
$$
There is a standard trick to get rid of the weight, such as $1+x^2$. In
$$
     Lf = \frac{1}{4}((1+x^2)f')'+af
$$
let
$$
     f(x) = g(\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx)=g(\tan^{-1}x).
$$
Then
$$
       Lf = \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1+x^2}g''(x)+ag
$$
Solving $Lf=\lambda f$ requires solving
$$
         g'' = 4(\lambda -a)(1+x^2)g.
$$
It is natural to try $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^{2n}$:
$$
     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n)(2n-1)a_{n}x^{2n-2}=4(\lambda-a)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^{2n}+4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^{2n+2}. $$
This gives a 3-term recursion relation, which leads to 2 independent solutions, both of which are even.